# TYPO3 Extension create plugin: No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am working on an extension with several plugins. Basically this works fine, but now I added a new plugin to my extension using the same "recipe". I added the plugin to a page and I keep getting this exception:

```
No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path "tt_content.list.20.extkey_pluginname"
```

https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1540246570

I cleared all possible caches, uninstalled and reinstalled the extension. Checked my code multiple times.

```
$extname = "$vendorname.$extkey";
```

**ext_localconf.php:**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    $extname,
    'studyplan',
    array('Course' => 'display')
);
```

**Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php:**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $extname, 
    'studyplan', 
    'Study plan'
);
```

Comment: It turns out, there was a typo. But it would be helpful to know how to troubleshoot these kind of problems.

Comment: What kind of typo, in which file?

Comment: Thanks for asking, but I seriously can't remember.

Comment: If you re asking for help and then find a solution it would be fair to provide an answer. "It was a typo" doesn't help anyone!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i just forgot to include the extensions Typoscript template to the maintemplate. Hope it helps some people

Answer (score 1):

I will agree with that this can be typo only.
And it can happen only in extension or plugin name.

It can be ether **$extname** or plugin name **'studyplan'** is not matching in **configurePlugin** and **registerPlugin** calls.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Clearing all caches helped.
In the admin panel, there is a tab called `Maintenance` (in the admin section). There you can clear additional caches (`Flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache`)